# How to set a field in a struct with an empty value?

Tags: rust, null, option-type

I am writing a TCP client and have a `conn` field in my client struct. My client implements two methods `new` to instantiate the struct and connect to open a connection to the server and set that as the value of the `conn` field

```
pub struct FistClient {
    addr: String,
    conn: TcpStream,
}

impl FistClient {
    pub fn new(ip: &str, port: &str) -> Self {
        FistClient {
            addr: String::from(ip) + ":" + &String::from(port),
            // conn: <some-defaullt-value>,
        }
    }

    pub fn connect(&mut self, ip: &str, port: &str) {
        let res = TcpStream::connect(&self.addr);
        match res {
            Ok(c) => self.conn = c,
            Err(_) => panic!(),
        }
    }
}
```

I want to set the `conn` field in the new method to some default value. In Go I can do something like `conn: nil` but it doesn't work here. I tried `Default::default()` too but that trait isn't implemented for `TCPStream` how should I set it to a default value?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's no `null` in Rust (and no Null Pointer Exception, Rust is designed for safety).

You must either

**1)** use an [option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/) (i.e. a field of type `Option<TcpStream>`)

**2)** or better: return a [result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/) when building the struct

Here, the best option would probably be to connect from inside a function returning a `Result<FistClient>`, so that you don't have to check whether your struct has a valid stream.

I would do something like this:

```
pub struct FistClient {
    addr: String,
    conn: TcpStream,
}

impl FistClient {
    pub fn new(ip: &str, port: &str) -> Result<Self> {
        let addr = format!("{}:{}", ip, port);
        let conn = TcpStream::connect(&addr)?;
        Ok(FistClient { addr, conn })
    }
}
```

Side note: It's really preferable to not build your applications with calls to `panic`, even when you think you're just building a dirty draft. [Handle errors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) instead.

Comment: How do you instantiate the object then? I am really new to Rust and am pretty lost, trying to do the same thing as you..

Comment: @d3Roux You instantiate it with `my_client = FirstClient::new(ip, port)?;` (the `?` is often replaced by local error handling depending on the logic of the application).

Answer (score 13):

In Rust, the idea of `null` is modelled with `Option`. You give a field the type `Option<TcpStream>` to indicate that it might not be there (`None`), or be a valid value (`Some(TcpStream)`).

```
pub struct FistClient {
    addr: String,
    conn: Option<TcpStream>,
}

impl FistClient {
    pub fn new(ip: &str, port: &str) -> Self {
        FistClient {
            addr: String::from(ip) + ":" + &String::from(port),
            conn: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn connect(&mut self, ip: &str, port: &str) {
        let res = TcpStream::connect(&self.addr);
        match res {
            Ok(c) => self.conn = Some(c),
            Err(_) => panic!(),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need to change your type to `Option<TCPStream>` if you would like to keep this call pattern. an `Option` expresses the possible lack of a value (I. e. null) with two enum variants: `Some(_)` and `None`.

Once you have this in place you can easily retrieve a mutable reference to the inner member by calling `as_mut` to retrieve an `Option<&mut T>`.